# How can I query data with two date ranges in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to execute this query to fetch 'Banners' between a date_start and a date_end.

```
$current_date = date('Y-m-d');
$banners = $this->Banner->find('all', 
                     array('conditions' => 
                               array("date_start >= " => $current_date, 
                               "date_end <= " => $current_date)
                     ));
```

I've attempted to use NOW() which seems to cause problems, I've tried using an "AND" condition and I've also concatenated the query with $current_date (eg. "date_start =>".$current_date)

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

**Edit**

Managed to get it working by switching the conditions around:

```
$banners = $this->Banner->find('all', array('conditions' => array("'$current_date' >=" >= "date_start", "'$current_date' <=" => 'date_end')));
```

Answer (score 2):

you should change your equation

date_start <= $current_date and
date_end >= $current date

lets say date_start is 1/5/2011
and date_end is 3/5/2011
and curr_date is 2/5/2011

notice that curr_date is bigger than start_date and smaller than end_date, in your condition you check the opposite

Comment: Cheers - I just realised that after actually thinking about my problem!